# right way to get object from jtable

Tags: java, swing, object, jtable

nice day for all;
i have table model extends AbstractTableModel add objects to jtable and its fine and work good
and have this code to get objects from table

```
        ListSelectionModel rowSM1 = carTable.getSelectionModel();
    rowSM1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
                return;
            if (carTable.getSelectedRow() < 0) {
                try {
                    throw new Exception();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                editMI.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.print(new CarTableModel(carsList).getCar(carTable.getSelectedRow())+"\n");
                    }
                });

            }
        }

    });
```

and its work and give me object of selected row
but when select other row give me him object and repeat it according selection
if second select repeat twice if third select repeat 3 time
like next :

first select

```
Car{id=1, carLicense=CarLicense{id=1, human=Human{id=2,
```

second select

```
Car{id=3, carLicense=CarLicense{id=3, human=Human{id=2,
Car{id=3, carLicense=CarLicense{id=3, human=Human{id=2,
```

third select

```
Car{id=2, carLicense=CarLicense{id=2, human=Human{id=1,
Car{id=2, carLicense=CarLicense{id=2, human=Human{id=1,
Car{id=2, carLicense=CarLicense{id=2, human=Human{id=1,
```

fourth select

```
Car{id=1, carLicense=CarLicense{id=1, human=Human{id=2,
Car{id=1, carLicense=CarLicense{id=1, human=Human{id=2,
Car{id=1, carLicense=CarLicense{id=1, human=Human{id=2,
Car{id=1, carLicense=CarLicense{id=1, human=Human{id=2,
```

and so on 
please any solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a new ActionListener every time you select a row from the table.
That's why you get that repeating output.

I can't see a lot of your code but I think the whole stuff controlling the selection of the list is superfluous.
The action event is triggered within the "editMI" component itself.

So it is enough to have:

```
               editMI.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.print(new CarTableModel(carsList).getCar(carTable.getSelectedRow())+"\n");
                    }
                });
```

Independently from the selection event of the table.

Comment: thank you that work fine i'm not considerate you give me point